# Python regex issue with strings

Tags: python, regex

Hi wonder if someone can help I've converted to Python from Perl and for the most part I love it.  However I struggle with regex in Python this is not as strong or easy as perl for anyway.  How do I use a list of exemption values(exemptions_list) to search another list which is being iterated in a for loop.  Problem is that the values in the for loop are slightly different from the search exemptions.

i.e. one of the exemptions is the string "default" but the variable coming in to be search is default_10 or default_20.  Likewise none is the search pattern but the share is called none_20 etc.  I don't really want to iterate over the search patterns as I am already iterating over the shares which come from another subprocess output.  So basically it never finds the string as it is looking for default_20 rather than default.  How can break down the variable coming in from shared_list so that python uses default from the variable to search again the strings in the exemptions_list.  The share variable is as stated generated differently for different systems subprocess output.

Many thanks

in Perl it would be easy.

```
if ( $share =~ /^.*_[\d\d]/ && $share !~ /$cust_id|$exemptions/ ) {
```

Python:

```
exemption_list = "none temp swap container"
shares_list [' this is dynamic and comes in with values such as none_20 temp_20, testtmp etc ]' 
def process_share_information(shares_list, customer_id):
    for share in shares_list: 
        share_match = re.search(share, exemption_list)
        if not share_match:
            print 'we have found a potentially bad share not in exemptions'
```

Comment: Please give a [Minimal, Viable, Complete Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with every question on Stack Overflow. As it stands, your code will not run.

Comment: not sure that is very helpful if the code ran then why would I be here ?  not really going to post pages of private code just looking for a little help on regex.

Comment: @Stu: What Kevin means is that your code is not valid Python. It has syntax errors.

Comment: Yes that is correct, it was was really meant as a discussion point.  Apologies I will try harder next time to get a good example first.

Answer (score 0):

Strips last `_\d\d` from string

```
re.sub(r'_\d\d$', '', string)
```

So to check for exemption do

```
>>> re.sub(r'_\d\d$', '', "none_20") in exemption_list
True
```

---

If searched words are in more general format than `name_\d\d`, iterate over exemptions instead.

```
>>> exemptions = "none temp swap container".split()
>>> shares_list = "this is dynamic and comes in with values such as none_20 asdfnone anonea temp_20, testtmp etc" 
>>> for e in exemptions:
...     print(e)
...     print(e in shares_list)
...     print(re.findall(r'\b\S*?{}\S*?\b'.format(e), shares_list))
...     print()
... 
none
True
['none_20', 'asdfnone', 'anonea']

temp
True
['temp_20']

swap
False
[]

container
False
[]
```

Or if you only need one result for whole string

```
>>> any(e in shares_list for e in exemptions)
True
```

Comment: Thanks I did think of this however unfortunately that would not fit with other exemptions if they were all of the format <name>_dd then yes.  However on some occasion the share value will be wwwwdddd_default_dddwwwddd etc.

Comment: maybe I should reverse it an do if exception_list in share  can I do this as the full list of exemptions or would I need to loop the exemptions also ?.

Comment: @Stu I've figured it was in `name_\d\d` format, since that was in your *perl* example. Please edit your question so it is more clear.

Comment: Apologies yes I understand.  Basically I have a string of exemptions that form part of a list of shares that I want to iterate over and if they are not in the exemption list then they need checked.  i.e. list  to shorten it all down say the strings exemptions are "default temp"  and I have a loop variable with share names coming in like with values like 'stuarttemp' I want to ignore this one as it has temp in the share name.  Likewise the next share is stu_0023_default_blah I would want to ignore this one.

Comment: Looks great, can you explain a little on what the logic is here, the findall method of re seems to be failing on my version of python.  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 181, in findall
    return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
TypeError: expected string or buffer

Comment: @Stu What do you not understand? I can't reproduce the error.